# How to avoid JSON deserialize / serialize in Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following code in a Web API controller in ASP.NET 2.0:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{controllerName}/{nodeId}/ConfigurationValues")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetConfigurationValues(string controllerName, byte nodeId, string code)
{
    string payload = ...

    HttpResponseMessage response = await deviceControllerRepository.ExecuteMethodAsync(controllerName, "GetNodeConfigurationValues", payload);

    string responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var configurationValues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ConfigurationValue>>(responseJson);

    return Ok(configurationValues);
}
```

How can I avoid having to de-serialize the responseJson into a .NET object before returning it as it already is in the correct JSON format?

I tried to change the method into returning HttpResponseMessage, but that resulted in incorrect JSON being passed back to the caller.

Comment: What does deviceControllerRepository do? and why can't you make it return object instead of HttpResponseMessage?

Comment: Could you write that string to the response and return Ok() without providing it the argument as you do now.

Comment: @Rob, Ok() will send 'text/plain' in Content-Type header.

Comment: Im not near a PC now but there should be Json method that controller exposes. I know that method takes an object but you can try passing it a string as well.

Comment: If you use just return Json("{\"Value\": 5}") you'll get following in body of output packet: "{\"Value\": 5}". It's not a valid json becaus of embracing quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ControllerBase` class has a `Content()` method for this purpose. Make sure you set correct Content-Type header in output packet:

```
return Content(responseJson, "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return ContentResult instead of Ok() for avoiding unnecessary serialization:

```
return new ContentResult
    {
        Content = responseJson,
        ContentType = "application/json",
        StatusCode = 200
    };
```

Comment: There is a Content() method that will construct ContentResult for you.